# Editing JSP in eclipse breaks special characters?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, utf-8, utf

I have a JSP file in eclipse. When I right click on it I can see that the encoding seems to be UTF-8.

When I see this file being rendered in the browser I can see that everything is ok. The text in the button is "Zurück" (German for "back").

As soon as I modify and save the file all the special german characters break.

"Zurück" -> -ZurÔøΩck

They look ok in eclipse but in the browser they look broken.

What could be the issue here ???

Comment: Set eclipse encoding to UTF-8. Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace : Text file encoding

Comment: It is already UTF-8 ...

Comment: what is the browser encoding? do you have `<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer I have is the following :

I wasn´t really able to fix it. The file was UTF-8, eclipse has UTF-8 as standard file encoding and everything else looked fine, too.

What I did then was what I should have done from the beginning: I encoded the special characters for JSP files and for javascript. This worked is a much cleaner approach then just wrinting everthing into the JSP file.